# Is that true that not every function $f(x,y)$ can be writen as $h(x) g(y)$?

Tags: functions

If not, why? Here $h$ and $g$ are two general function.

Comment: Have you tried this with simple examples, like $f(x,y)=x+y$?

Comment: No... but how to show it cannot be written as $h(x) g(y)$? Thank you and thank you for editing the question.

Comment: @Rodriguez Try plugging in $y=1$ or $x=1$.

Comment: $f(x,1)=x+1=h(x)g(1)$ or $f(1,y)=1+y=h(1) g(y)$, hence $h(x)=(x+1)/g(1)$ and $g(y)=(1+y)/h(1)$ or $h(1)=2/g(1)=(1+y)/g(y)$? sorry, cannot proceed

Comment: This may be somewhat advanced right now, but you may want to check the following paper: [MR1687171 (2000g:26008)](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1687171)  
Cowsik, R. C.; Kłopotowski, A.; Nadkarni, M. G. *When is $f(x,y)=u(x)+v(y)$?* Proc. Indian Acad. Sci. Math. Sci. **109** (1999), no. 1, 57–64.

Comment: You have $1+y = h(1)g(y)$ and $x+1 = h(x)g(1)$. Then $(1+y)(x+1) = h(1)g(y)h(x)g(1)$. Substitute $h(1)g(1) = 2$ there, along with $h(x)g(y) = x+y$ and see the magic happen.

Comment: Benjamin Miller has some significant generalizations of their results, see [MR2232198 (2007a:03056)](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2232198) Miller, Benjamin D. *Coordinatewise decomposition, Borel cohomology, and invariant measures*. Fund. Math. **191** (2006), no. 1, 81–94. And also [MR2342622 (2008g:03081)](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2342622) Miller, Benjamin D.
*Coordinatewise decomposition of group-valued Borel functions*. 
Fund. Math. **196** (2007), no. 2, 119–126. Both papers are accessible at https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/47430894/Web/publications.html

Comment: Sorry, $(1+1)(1+1)=h(1)g(1)h(1)g(1)=2*2=4$, did not see the magic :(

Comment: @andres, made up a simple illustration with a rectangle...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing must happen if we know $f(x,y) = g(x) h(y),$ which is that we must get equality on diagonals for four points in a rectangle: suppose we have the four points $(a,b),$ $(c,b),$ $(a,d),  $ $(c,d).$ We must have
$$ f(a,b) f(c,d) = f(a,d) f(c,b), $$ because $f(x,y) = g(x) h(y)$ means both sides equal $g(a)g(c)h(b)h(d).$

First we take the easiest example, $f(x,y) = x+y.$ The left hand side of
$$ f(a,b) f(c,d) = f(a,d) f(c,b) $$
is $(a+b)(c+d) = ac + ad+bc+bd. $ The right hand side is
$(a+d)(c+b) = ac + ab+cd+bd. $
For concreteness, take $a=1,$ $b=10,$ $c=100,$ $d=1000.$ The two values are not equal.

The cocycle condition is also sufficient. If we always have $f(x,y)=0,$ then take $g(x) = 0,$ $h(y) = 0.$

If, instead, there is some point such that $f(A,B) \neq 0,$ we can continue by using
$$ f(x,y) f(A,B) = f(x,B) f(A,y).  $$
Therefore define
$$ g(x) = \frac{f(x,B)}{f(A,B)}, $$
$$ h(y) = f(A,y). $$ This way,
$$ g(x) h(y) =  \frac{f(x,B) f(A,y)}{f(A,B)}.$$

Comment: But is this also sufficient?

Comment: And that's the point of those papers I linked to, how the condition is equivalent to a hidden cocycle structure.

Comment: Take $f(x,y)=x+y$ for instance. For points can be (1,1),(1,2),(2,1),(2,2). Hence, $2*4=3*3$...

Comment: @Strants also suffices